# How to read files with same name in two different folders in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am very new to Python and trying to read files with same name in two different folders.
creating dataframes per new_name_file is tedious.
How to optimize the code.

**Example Code**:
to read team_ABC.txt in differnt folders

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\2020\team_ABC.txt',sep='\t')
df2 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\2021\team_ABC.txt',sep='\t')
```

**Example Code**:
to read team_XYZ.txt in differnt folders

```
df3 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\2020\team_XYZ.txt',sep='\t')
df4 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\2021\team_XYZ.txt',sep='\t')
```

I want to read same named files from folder 2020 with folder 2021.
is there a way in which I can achieve it in more optimized manner like:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\2020\team_{same_name}.txt',sep='\t')
df2 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\2021\team_{same_name}.txt',sep='\t')
```

Comment: Has your question been answered @LearnerBegineer?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
import os


def read_csv_file(team_name):
    base_path = "C:/Users/"
    df2020 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(base_path, "2020", f"team_{team_name}.txt"), sep='\t')
    df2021 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(base_path, "2021", f"team_{team_name}.txt"), sep='\t')
    return df2020, df2021

df1, df2 = read_csv_file("XYZ")
```

Comment: there are many filenames : Example : team_ABC.txt, team_PQR.txt, team_XYZ.txt . (how to read all such team_{}.txt in one variable)

Comment: Do you only want to read from folders 2020 and 2021?

Comment: we are explicitly mentioning team_XYZ.txt can we use a for loop which will read all same name txt file in two differnt folders

Comment: yes i want to read only from folders 2020 and 2021.( same named txt files in 2020 and 2021)

Comment: @LearnerBegineer what about this?

Answer (score 1):

if your current working directory is the 2020 folder you can use the ../ command and it will look something like this

```
../2021+filename
```